# How to get the element object by using JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

Does anyone know now can I get the element object by using JQuery?

For Example: 
I have the following code to pass in the element object into the function

**HTML:**

```
<table>
    <tr>
      <td>
          <input type='text' ID='test' onchange='test(this)' />
          <input type='text' ID='test_1' onchange='test(this)' />
          <input type='text' ID='test_2' onchange='test(this)' />
          <input type='text' ID='test_3' onchange='test(this)' />
      </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
function test(obj) {
    var parent = $($($(obj).parent()).parent()).parent();
}
```

Instead of passing the object over from html ( onchange='test(this)' ), any way I can capture the object by using jquery within the function by using the input ID?

Comment: `.parent()` returns a jQuery object. There is no need to keep wrapping it in `$()`

Comment: Are you trying to capture the `table` as an object? The `<tr>`, `<td>`?

Comment: What do you want to select? Are you talking abou the table? In that case you do $(obj).parent().parent().parent(). Please specify what you want to select.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you script executes after the element exists (for example: onload or at the end of your body), you can remove the `onchange` attribute entirely from your HTML and do:

```
$('#test').change(function(){
    // `this` refers to the input element
    var parent = $(this).parents().eq(2); //.parents needs backets
});
```

Comment: $(this).parents().eq(0) or .eq(2) .... i can't remember which way it stacks the parents but this a better way instead of calling the parent function 3 times.

Comment: @ShanRobertson I agree that is nicer. I'm not sure which would be more efficient, but it's definitely more concise. I've updated accordingly

Answer (score 1):

**EDITED AND UPDATED**

Ah, I think I understand you now....

**HTML**

```
<table>
    <tr>
      <td>
          <input type='text' ID='test' />
      </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(function() {
    var obj;
    $('#test').on('change',function() {
       obj = this; // from this point on, obj is your INPUT
       var v = this.val(); // v is now the value of the INPUT (what was typed)
       obj = this.closest('table'); // obj is now the TABLE
       obj = this.closest('tr'); // obj is now the ROW
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the "id" property to get the javascript/DOM element like so:

```
function test(obj) {
  var parent = $(obj).parent().parent().parent()[0];
  //do something here
}
```

Comment: The `table` doesn't have an id, and if it did that would be the same as `var parent = $(obj).parent().parent().parent()[0];`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `onchange` attribute to add the event handler, use jQuery to register it using .change()

```
$('table').on('change', 'input[type="text"]' function(){
    //here this points to the text element
    var $tr = $(this).closest('tr')
})
```